# How to write an SQL query based on properties of the oldest element of a has-many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

Given the following example datamodels/tables:
*(specified in pseudo-Ruby/Rails for brevity's sake)*

```
class User
  has_many :orders
end
```

```
class Order
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  ordered_at :timestamp
end
```

```
class Product
  name :string
  price :decimal
end
```

(and each of these tables also has a unique 'id' identifier field that is its primary key, and a joins table connecting `Order` and `Product` also exists)

I would like to select all users, for which e.g. their *oldest* Order (with the earliest `ordered_at`), contains more than **n** products.

How can this be done?

What I've tried so far: I tried using a `JOIN`, but then we end up looking at *all* orders rather than only the oldest. I've also tried to use `DISTINCT`/`DISTINCT ON` but I have no idea how to combine this properly with (a) selecting the users and (b) doing a check for the count of all related products.

*I am using Postgres, but if a DB-agnostic SQL answer exists, that would be much appreciated as well.*

Comment: If you ask a question about SQL, then it would help if the SQL guys can understand the question. And not all of them may speak "pseudo-Ruby/Rails". So please translate that to `CREATE TABLE` statements. Also add some sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text form.

Comment: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. PS There is even a tag for questions involving this faq [tag:greatest-n-per-group].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: I just found that duplicate link googling 'site:stackoverflow.com sql select all users, for which e.g. their oldest Order'. That is not even clear, it's just cut & pasted from your message but it is already clear enough even with your particular business & DB strings.

Comment: It is not clear what your tables actually look like in Postgres.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I would phrase this using `distinct on`.  The basic idea would be:

```
select o.*
from (select distinct on (o.user_id) o.user_id, o.order_id, o.ordered_at, count(*) as num_products
      from orders o join
           orderproducts op
           on op.order_id = o.order_id
      group by o.user_id, o.order_id, o.ordered_at
      order by o.user_id, o.ordered_at asc
     ) o
where num_products >= n
```